# How search text in edit textfield in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

How can I handle event in EditText Field?.

Example: when I enter some text in EditText then what I have to do generate custom layout?
    below is my screen.Does any one have idea please tell me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 EditField text=new EditField()
        {
            protected boolean keyChar(char key, int status, int time) 
            {
                if((int)key==10)//10 is ASCII code of "Enter" key
                {
                    add(new LabelField("New Field"));

                }
                return super.keyChar(key, status, time);

            }
        };
        add(text);
```

after enter all data just click on enter then new label will appear on screen